# Dataset for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: csv

I am trying to do Sentiment Analysis for amazon product review us. I tried searching for data set as csv format, but couldn't find one. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It's in this drive [location](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bz8a_Dbh9Qhbfll6bVpmNUtUcFdjYmF2SEpmZUZUcVNiMUw1TWN6RDV3a0JHT3kxLVhVR2M).

File named 'amazon_review_full_csv.tar.gz'